# How to jUnit test hibernate transactions?

Tags: spring, hibernate, junit, transactions

I have a transaction method that looks like this:

```
@Transactions
public processTransaction(MyAPi api);
```

In order to make sure that hibernate transactions are functioning okay, I would like to test if the DB rolls back in Junit.

How do we do it?

Comment: First thing that came to mind would be using a in-memory db, do the transaction and then validate the contents of the db. Upon using google I found this page though [Testing - Transaction management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/testing.html#testcontext-tx) which may be of help to you.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [DBUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/) - it's designed to assist with this exact type of testing. You can define table states, build up in-memory or physical databases, then perform your tests and compare the table state afterwards. You can also use it to provide a known-state database before each test runs.